# connection string reading data from excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, connection-string, absolute-path

I am trying to read data from excel file in asp.net. I have added the connection string to webConfig file:

```
<add name="xls" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=HPM_DB.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>
```

But it shows me an errormessage when I run this query:

string query = "Select * from [IO_Definition$]";

IO_Definition is the name of the spreadsheet in my excel file. I also added the excel file to the App_Data folder of the website.

The error is:

The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'IO_Definition$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

The thing is, when I write the absolute path of the excel file in the connectionString it does work. Is there anyway I can make it work without writing the absolute path?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that for this sort of 'file' connection, the OleDb provider needs, as you've already found, the absolute path to the file. *Historically*, we've done this with `Server.MapPath`, in which case you'd do something like:

```
<connectionstrings>
    <add name="xls" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"/>
</connectionstrings>

String connString;
OleDbConnection conn;

connString = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xls"].ConnectionString;
connString = connString + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/HPM_DB.xls");

conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

conn.Open();
...
```

which works, but you need to either do all that every time you want to open a connection and query the data, or break it out into a connection factory class.

A neater way to do it is this:

```
<connectionstrings>
    <add name="xls" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;
    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HPM_DB.xls;"/>
</connectionstrings>

OleDbConnection conn;

conn = new OleDbConnection(Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xls"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
...
```

At runtime the `|DataDirectory|` token in the connection string acts as a macro which silently does all that `Server.MapPath` stuff for you.